# What is the result of "(0u - 1)" modulo 2^N?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

[basic.fundamental] p2 just says

> arithmetic for the unsigned type is performed modulo 2<sup>N</sup>

Consider this example

```cpp
auto t = 0u -1;
```

According to usual arithmetic conversions, both operands will have unsigned int types. The arithmetic result should perform modulo 2<sup>N</sup>, in any calculator, `-1 mod 4294967296` always gives `-1`(assume `N` equals 32). I don't see that the modulo can make the result fall into the range [0, 4294967296]. Is anything wrong?

Comment: "modulo" in the mathematical sense, not the `%` sense.

Comment: If we do it the other way, like `4294967295u + 1`, then that becomes `4294967296` which modulo `4294967296` is equal to `0`. From that it can be deduced that `0u - 1` must be equal to `4294967295`.

Comment: @PasserBy I just do the calculation of `-1 Modulo 4294967295` in calculators.

Comment: The usual math convention is `-1 mod x = x - 1`.

Comment: `%` is not modulo, it is a _remainder_ operator in C++. The difference between modulo and remainder is important when dealing with negative values.

Comment: Thanks. I used the wrong online calculator to get the wrong result.

Comment: In fact the standard gives the specific example that: "The value −1 of a signed integer type has the same representation as the largest value of the corresponding unsigned type."

Comment: @heapunderrun Another thing that confuses me is when we say algebraic quotient, which one do we intend to refer to? For example, `-1 /2`, the quotient could be `-1` with remainder `1`, or the quotient is `-0.5`, which one is the algebraic quotient?

Comment: Modular arithmetic does not have negative numbers, so IDK how did you come to `-1 mod 4294967296`. Like, arithmetic modulo `2` has numbers `0` and `1`. Similarly, arithmetic modulo 2^N has numbers in the range from 0 to 2^N - 1.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer *Modular arithmetic does not have negative numbers* This is the key point here.

Comment: _This is the key point here_ And what is the problem, then? `a - b` means `a + (-b)`, where `-b` means «the additive inverse element for `b` in the modulo 2^N additive group» Additive inverse for `x` is the element adding which to `x` would give additive neutral (`0`). So, for `1`, the additive inverse is `2^N - 1`. `0 - 1` in modulo 2^N arithmetic is `0 + (2^N - 1)`.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer The answer to this problem is the mathematical modulo should obey: `bq + R = a,  q ∈ Z, 0 ≤ R ≤ | b |` That is what you said, the remainder should be a positive number.

Comment: «arithmetic modulo X» is not the same as «taking `mod X` in ℤ»

Comment: @LanguageLawyer what is the result of `-1` arithmetic modulo `2`? The quotient is `-1` and the remainder is `1`?

Comment: Again, modular arithmetic is not about quotient and remainder. You have a set S with two elements _e_ and _x_ and a function _f_ : S×S → S which is "defined" as f(e, e) = e, f(e, x) = f(x, e) = x, f(x, x) = e. Thats your arithmetic modulo 2. You can introduce a function _opp_ : S → S defined as that for each _z_, its result is such that f(z, opp(z)) = e. So, opp(x)=x. Usually, we use infix + instead of _f_ and `-` instead of _opp_. So, f(a, b) is written as a+b, and f(a, opp(b)) as a+(-b), which is usually shortened to a-b. So, -1=1 (e is denoted by 0, x — by 1).

Comment: @LanguageLawyer In short, do you mean `modular arithmetic` has the same meaning as `a ≡ b (mod n)`, in this example, `n = 2^32`  Right?

Answer (score 1):

Modulo operation itself is ambiguous. It is defined as this:

> In nearly all computing systems, the quotient q and the remainder r of a divided by n satisfy the following conditions:
>
> > q ∈ ℤ
> > a = nq + r
> > |r| < |n|

(from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation))

By that, we have two `r`s with positive and negative signs. In C++, the remainder's sign follows by the dividend's sign, so what you stated is right.

However, the actual computer calculation doesn't work like that; `0u - 1` is simply performed like this, not using modulo:

```
    0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
  - 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
  -----------------------------------------
    1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

this results `t` be 2^32 - 1, being the same as positive modulo 2^32.

In conclusion, C++ unsigned integers are not actually calculated by modulo. Still, it appears to be the same as what we "performed modulo".

Comment: In mathematic, is the remainder must be a positive number?

Comment: @xmh0511 Due to ambiguity of its definition, it depends on contexts. The remainder don't have to be positive, but mostly it is and I personally prefer positive ones to negative ones